# Solve the integral $\int\ln(2x)\mathrm{d}x$ through IBP

Tags: calculus

I have a homework assignment that asks me to integrate composed functions such as $\int\ln(2x)\mathrm{d}x$ by parts. I'm confused because I thought integration required two functions to be multiplied together, not composed. All the examples in my textbook use multiplied functions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I would recommend you to notice that $\ln(2x) = \ln(2) + \ln(x)$ whenever $x > 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\int\ln(2x)~\mathrm{d}x=\int1\cdot\ln(2x)~\mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: Even bigger hint:
$$\int \ln(2x) dx = \int 1dx \cdot \ln(2x)$$

Comment: @JosephCamacho .... to beginning calculus students, it looks like you moved $\ln(2x)$ outside the integral, which is erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

This actually is a common trick for inverse functions, thanks to a derivative rule you might have learned. Lorago already gave the key observation, but I want to elaborate more on its main use case (at least in the sense of a calculus class) and how to utilize it (with a different example).

---

**Inverse Functions & Derivatives:**

Let $f$ have inverse function $f^{-1}$. Then

$$\newcommand{\f}{f^{-1}}
\newcommand{\dv}[1]{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}x}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
(f \circ \f)(x) = (\f \circ f)(x) = x$$

Now, notice:

$$(f \circ \f)(x) = x \implies \dv{} (f \circ \f)(x) = f'(\f(x)) \cdot (\f)'(x) = 1$$

Then, solving for $(\f)'(x)$,
$$
(\f)'(x) = \frac{1}{(f' \circ \f)(x)}
$$

Equivalently, replacing $f$ with $\f$ and vice versa,

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{( (\f)' \circ f )(x)}$$

This latter form is nicer to have when you're given a function and want to find its derivative, and know its inverse.

---

**Inverse Functions & Integration by Parts:**

Integrating inverse functions is a bit of a pain (though a few functions can be exceptions to that, such as $\ln(x)$). However, evidently, differentiating them is easier.

So what do I do if I want the integral of some function which is "obviously" an inverse function? That is, if I know $f$ and want $\int f(x) \, dx$, and $f$ is the inverse to $\f$, what should I do?

Integration by parts works just nicely with this.

Say, for instance, $f(x) = \arctan(x)$. Its inverse, $\f(x) = \tan(x)$, has derivative $(\f)'(x) = \sec^2(x)$.

The trick, then, is to write

$$\int f(x) \, \dd x = \int 1 \cdot f(x) \, \dd x$$

It's a mathematician's favorite trick, to multiply something by $1$ but somehow make life easier. (Or to add/subtract the same thing, another common trick.) And this is totally fine -- a constant function is still a function! In my example, then,

$$\int \arctan(x) \, \dd x = \int 1 \cdot \arctan(x) \, \dd x$$

As stated, inverse functions are easy to differentiate, so this makes $1$ the function to integrate. Well, we know

$$\dv{} \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

but if we don't know this, we can use the rule from before to realize that

$$\dv{} \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{( \sec^2 \circ \arctan )(x)} = \Big( \cos(\arctan(x)) \Big)^2$$

which simplifies to the previous formula with some trig.

Integration by parts will say that

$$\int f(x) g'(x) \, \dd x = f(x) g(x) - \int f'(x) g(x) \, \dd x$$

(In our example, $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ and $g'(x) = 1$.) Then

$$\int \arctan(x) \, \dd x = x \arctan(x) - \int \frac{x}{1+x^2} \, \dd x$$

This remaining integral can be solved easily with a $u$-substitution.